# How to inject CSS in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, css, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.aparat.com/aleffamily/live2");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement styleEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("style");
        IHTMLStyleElement element = (IHTMLStyleElement)styleEl.DomElement;
        IHTMLStyleSheetElement styleSheet = element.styleSheet;
        styleSheet.cssText = @"body {background-color:transparent !important; margin: 0px auto; overflow: hidden; }.live__content{display:none;}.chat__footer{display:none;}.chat__header{display:none}#header{display:none}.in-chat-avatar{display:none}.message__username{font-style:italic;font-weight: 800!important;color:ff8f0f !important}.message__text{font-style:italic;font-weight: 400!important;color:ff8f0f !important}.chat__content{ background-color:transparent  !important}.chat{ background-color:transparent  !important}";
        head.AppendChild(styleEl);

    }


}
```

}

This code has not worked for me and I am getting this error

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'IHTMLStyleSheetElement' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)    C:\Users\aleffamily\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs
>   30  13  WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: I had this same problem. What worked for me was this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33fd33f7-e857-4f6f-978e-fd486eba7174/how-to-inject-style-into-a-page?forum=iewebdevelopment (basically, add the `<style>` after a `<div>` or something)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What are you trying to reference with `IHTMLStyleElement` and `IHTMLStyleSheetElement`? Its not anywhere in the .NET framework.

Just modify your code to write the contents of the generic `HtmlElement` type instead by writing the contents of the `.InnerText` or `.InnerHtml` with your stylesheet

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.aparat.com/aleffamily/live2");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement styleEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("style");
        styleEl.InnerHtml = @"body {background-color:transparent !important; margin: 0px auto; overflow: hidden; }.live__content{display:none;}.chat__footer{display:none;}.chat__header{display:none}#header{display:none}.in-chat-avatar{display:none}.message__username{font-style:italic;font-weight: 800!important;color:ff8f0f !important}.message__text{font-style:italic;font-weight: 400!important;color:ff8f0f !important}.chat__content{ background-color:transparent  !important}.chat{ background-color:transparent  !important}";
        head.AppendChild(styleEl);

    }
}
```

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: A propriedade não é suportada neste tipo de HtmlElement. em System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.set_InnerHtml(String value)` <-- Basically, the property is not supported for the style tag.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Sorry to hear it's not  working for you. I tested it and it is still working on my end. Try using the code I posted exactly, or update your .net framework

Comment: That's **exactly** what I've done. I just found other methods that worked and went with those.

Comment: Yet I'm **interested** in why it didnt work on your machine and what other method did work for you?

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was `webBrowser1.Document.Write($"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>{...}</style></head><body></body></html>");`. I'm using .Net 4.7.2. You can see on this album that it throws that exception: https://imgur.com/a/YVR0oVG The `wb_content` is a web browser control, that navigates to `about:blank`. The style is applied on the `DocumentCompleted` event.